# F# function like reduce that return different type

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am new to functional programming and I can't find a function like reduce to build an AgreggateRoot given an EventStream:

```
List.reduce ((aggregate, event) -> aggregate) eventList
```

As I understand the reduce function only works with parameters of the same type of the output

Comment: Generally you'll use something like map to transform arguments so they're of a consistent type (if I understand your question)

Comment: No, I want the reduce function but the total parameters must be of another type than the element

Comment: Are you using the term "Aggregate Root" [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root)?

Comment: Yes, you transform the parameters so they match your aggregate (or in the other order if you want the result to differ from the aggregate)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think yes. i.e. I have the Aggregate Root Customer and I have to rebuild it based on its events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for fold. The main caveat with a fold is it requires you to provide an initial value for the output, instead of using the first element, but this is usually what you want when the output type is different than the elements.

Comment: This is the right solution. I tough that fold produce an output of the same type of the elements. Thanks

Comment: Fold can also be used to produce an output of the same type as the elements, and frequently is.